# Jealous / Envy Choosing the right word

Tags: meaning, word-difference

If "jealousy is when you worry someone will take what you have ... envy is wanting what someone else has" So I think only the second sentence is correct. Am I right?

> 1) My girlfriend is **jealous** of my success.
>
> 2) My girlfriend **envies** my success.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, that is how the words should be used.

In practice, many people use jealous(y) for both cases since it is usually clear from context which meaning applies, and envy is falling out of use.

Answer (score 0):

No. Both are correct.

"**being jealous**" means "*feeling unhappy that you don't have something some other person has*" just like "**envying**" - "*feeling unhappy that you don't have something some other person has*".

Comment: Mostly right, though notice that in more formal usage one can also feel jealousy (as protectiveness) for what one *does* have. This is not true of envy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you mean.

Your girlfriend *envies* your success if she wants to be as successful and resents that she is not.

Your girlfriend is *jealous* of your success if she resent anyone who tries to take or diminish it.